# Convert dataframe dict to table in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the output from

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(get_data)
display(df_data)
```

Output

```
'f_data':[{'fid': '9.3', 'lfid': '39.3'}, {'fid': '839.4', 'lfid': '739.3'}]
```

Needed output format like below

f_data

| fid | lfid |
| --- | --- |
| 9.3 | 39.3 |
| 839.4 | 739.3 |

Answer (score 1):

Try with `dict` get the correct key

```
d = {'f_data':[{'fid': '9.3', 'lfid': '39.3'}, {'fid': '839.4', 'lfid': '739.3'}]}
out = pd.DataFrame(d['f_data'])
Out[147]: 
     fid   lfid
0    9.3   39.3
1  839.4  739.3
```